# jquery animation & CSS Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-float

I am trying to fix the css  position in the  with jquery animation effect in the below code.

my green and orange span running out of control on mouse hover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.box1{
        width:40px;
        height:13px;
        float:left;
        font-size:.6em; color:#fff; background:#99CC00;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
.box2{
        width:40px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        font-size:.6em; color:#fff; background:#FF6600;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-top:1px;
        opacity:.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
            $('span').hover(function() {

                   $(this).stop().css({ 'z-index': '999999', 'position': 'absolute', 'float': 'left'}).animate({ marginTop: '0px', marginLeft: '0px', top: '0', left: '0', width: '200px', height: '125px', padding: '0px' }, 700, 'swing');


                }, function() {

                    $(this).stop().css({ 'z-index': '0', 'border': '0px' }).fadeIn('slow').animate({ marginTop: '0px', marginLeft: '0px', top: '0', left: '0', width: '40px', height: '13px', padding: '0px' }, 700, 'swing');


                });
            });

</script>


</head>

<body>
<table width="160" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="40" height="40" valign="top" bgcolor="#e4e4e4">
        <span class="box1">Hello ji</span>
        <span class="box2">Sanket</span>    </td>
    <td width="40" height="40" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40" height="40" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40" height="40" valign="top" bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

New to jquery, help much appreciated.

Comment: FYI - Providing a working example of the problem code goes **much** further than posting code when you are asking for assistance. If your web page is not public, use a tool like jsfiddle.net to post the relevant portions of the code. I made a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/sqCN5/1/) for you this time. :)

Comment: You have to describe the final look! The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Dutchie432 - Well dutchie. Yeah right. I love to make JSfiddles too, but it's good for SO and his future to paste codes on the place. Or one day... if they close JSFiddle.... SO will remain **EMPTY!** ;))

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified that in **in addition** to posting code, a working link goes a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
top: '0', left: '0',
```

from both `animate` function parametres

and remove

```
, 'position': 'absolute'
```

from first `css` function paramteres

Add:

```
position:absolute;
```

to `.box1` and `.box2` css classes.

Add

```
z-index:10;
```

to `.box1` css class

Add

```
top: 25px;    
z-index:0;
```

to `.box2` css class

Set on `.box2`

```
margin-top:0px;
```

to prevent shake.

Is that what you want?

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/M9JkP/4/

Comment: Removing (top: '0', left: '0', ) is working fine but second <span> over place and hide first <span> :( check in browser

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I understood it well, but if you do it like below, the span elements dont change the position

```
$(function() {
            $('span').hover(function() {

                   $(this).stop().css({  'float': 'left'}).animate({ marginTop: '0px', marginLeft: '0px', width: '200px', height: '125px', padding: '0px' }, 700, 'swing');


                }, function() {

                    $(this).stop().css({ 'border': '0px' }).fadeIn('slow').animate({ marginTop: '0px', marginLeft: '0px', width: '40px', height: '13px', padding: '0px' }, 700, 'swing');


                });
            });
```

Comment: +1 GREAT! just great! Looks like you read minds! ;D like like

Comment: Removing (top: '0', left: '0', ) is working fine but second <span> over place and hide first <span> :( check in browser

Answer (score 1):

I played around with it a little bit and got, what I think is, the correct result based on what it appears you are trying to do. I've also made an `expandMenu()` and `collapseMenu()` jQuery function to allow easy expanding/collapsing using `$(this).expandMenu();`. For Demonstration, I also added the `collapseMenu()` call to the `click()` binding so when an expended item is clicked, it collapses.

*Working Sample:* http://jsfiddle.net/sqCN5/4/

**Updated CSS**

```
span{
    position: absolute;    
}
.box1{
    width:40px;
    height:13px;
    float:left;
    font-size:.6em; 
    color:#fff; 
    background:#99CC00;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.box2{
    top:25px;
    width:40px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:.6em; 
    color:#fff; 
    background:#FF6600;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top:1px;
    opacity:.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}
```

**Updated JS**

```
$('span').hover(function() {
    $(this).expandMenu();
}, function() {
    $(this).collapseMenu();
}).click(function(){
    $(this).collapseMenu();
});

$.fn.collapseMenu= function() {
    $(this)
        .stop()
        .css({ 
            'border': '0px' 
        })
        .fadeIn('slow')
        .animate({ 
            width: '40px', 
            height: '13px', 
            padding: '0px' 
        }, 700,'swing', function(){
            $(this).css({'z-index': '0'});
        });
    return ($(this));    
 };

$.fn.expandMenu= function() {
   $(this)
       .stop()
       .css({ 
           'z-index': '999999', 
           'border' : '1px solid #000'
       })
       .animate({ 
           width: '200px', 
           height: '125px', 
           padding: '0px' 
       }, 700, 'swing');
    return ($(this));    
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 'position': 'absolute', and it seems better:

http://jsfiddle.net/gy7t9/

Comment: you are doing good but <table><td> should not be shake, these green and orange layer should overlay on table

Comment: That's what happens when don't don't specify your requirements accurately. ;)